# Safari 11 "prevent cross-site tracking" breaking facebook login

Tags: javascript, safari, facebook-login

When the user turns on Safari's "prevent cross-site tracking", Facebook login `response.status` is `unknown`, is there any way I can get the login information?

> The same code works fine in Chrome

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cause of the problem**

If you use `FB.getLoginStatus` to get the `accessToken`, it's can't work on the safari that it enables the **Prevent cross-site tracking**

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/?locale=en_US

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    ...
    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
  }
 });
```

---

**Solution**

Get the `accessToken` through the `code` in the redirected URL

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.2?locale=en_us

*example*

**step1. open the OAuth dialog**

Your redirect_uri is `https://www.sample.com.tw/login`

```
 GET https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
    client_id={app-id}
    &redirect_uri=https://www.sample.com.tw/login
```

**step2. get the code**

you can get the code in the URL after Facebook redirect to your page, it will be like:

```
https://www.sample.com.tw/login?code=ABCDEFG
```

**step3. get the access token through your server side API**

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
   client_id={app-id}
   &redirect_uri=https://www.sample.com.tw/login
   &client_secret={app-secret}
   &code=ABCDEFG
```

> Your app secret(client_secret) should never end up in client code.

Comment: That looks ok, however how do i then call FB API using js sdk?

Comment: Do you have more detail about the question?

Comment: We use FB SDK for multiple reasons, one of them - to get access token, but thats just one. I sure can move the client to follow manual login approach, however that leaves SDK uninitialized and therefore no API calls will work - access token is not set. Are there any kind of best practices to get both - manual login flow and the sdk initialized to use it to call FB API?

Answer (score -1):

Try disabling cookie policy. I had similar issue with Google API, and this piece of code solved it. Hope it will also work for Facebook login

```
auth2 = window.gapi.auth2.init({
    client_id: 'xxx',
    cookiepolicy: 'none',
  });
```

Reference: https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/342

Comment: Thanks, I can't find out how to turn off cookie policy in facebook login. Do you have any Suggestions?